# My map marker display at a different location instead of current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have written code to display Google map. But in the output my marker is displayed at a different location instead of my current location. As you can see in the actual result, the marker and blue dot are at different positions. How can I fix this...?

I have tried a lot of method but found nothing.

**Activity File**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private Location lastLocation;

    private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;

    private static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

            checkUserLocationPermission();
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }


    }

    public boolean checkUserLocationPermission(){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},Request_User_Location_Code);
            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},Request_User_Location_Code);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode){

            case Request_User_Location_Code:
                if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        if(googleApiClient == null){

                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }

                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        lastLocation = location;

        if(currentUserLocationMarker != null)
        {
            currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLongitude() , location.getLatitude());

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("User cuurent Location");

        currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(12));

        if(googleApiClient != null){

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient , locationRequest , this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

**Expected**

Map Marker display at the current location.

**Actual**

But in output I am getting the marker and blue dot at different position. Result:

[image: Actual result]

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Note that you're using the [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) FusedLocationProviderApi. Please consider switching to [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html).